# Issues with /home partition and a fresh install

Tags: mount

I had my /home one partition and /root on another, swap also had its own partition at the end of the drive as well. I of course kept all my important documents and family photo's on /home

For reasons to long for an explanation I decided too re-install Ubuntu 10.04. During the installation I assigned Ubuntu to be installed on its previous partition / and assigned the previous home to be used as /home, I did not mark /home to be formatted only used.

Upon booting into my new fresh Ubuntu installation I find that all my old documents, photo's and other important things to be missing. The partition is mounted and being used it's just showing the data that was previously in the directory..

so I guess my question would be how can I get Ubuntu to understand that data was there I wanted to show in my new installation..

I can do basic things with ubuntu but a step-by-step would be best if such solution existed to solve this. thank you

Answer (score 1):

To make it clear:

> The partition is mounted and being used it's just showing the data that was previously in the directory..

Do you mean if previously you had an image called a.jpg at path: /home/username/a.jpg, it went missing.
While if it was at: /home/username/directory/a.jpg, it is still there?

Other thing I would like you to check is Did you change your username from previous installation. If thats the case then you /home should have two folders one with previous username (holding all the data) and one with new username (with fresh start).

I'm just assuming things here as I couldn't understand question correctly.